# Why does npm start give error in node.js?

Tags: node.js, npm

Every time I try to run npm start for create-react-app, it gives me this error. I've uninstalled node.js, reinstalled it and done everything I can think of, but I can't seem to fix it. Here is my error:

```
> react-scripts start

/Users/Eduardo/my-app/node_modules/ajv/lib/keyword.js:65
      throw new Error('custom keyword definition is invalid: '  + this.errorsText(validateDefinition.errors));
      ^

Error: custom keyword definition is invalid: data.errors should be boolean
    at Ajv.addKeyword (/Users/Eduardo/my-app/node_modules/ajv/lib/keyword.js:65:13)
    at module.exports (/Users/Eduardo/my-app/node_modules/ajv-errors/index.js:10:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Eduardo/my-app/node_modules/schema-utils/src/validateOptions.js:22:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Eduardo/.npm/_logs/2019-02-10T01_38_44_462Z-debug.log
```

Comment: you might have a different version of node since you uninstalled it.  remove your node_modules folder and npm install and then try npx react-scripts start.

Answer (score 0):

For launch React you need:

1. [Click](https://nodejs.org/en/) here to navigate to the Node.js
   homepage in a new tab.
2. You should see links to download Node.js. Click on the download link
   of your choice. Follow the subsequent instructions to install
   Node.js and npm. If you've already installed Node.js, that's okay,
   do it anyway.
3. Create a new folder
4. Open nodejs terminal there
5. Make `npm init react-app .`
6. Make `npm start`

[More details about setting React app here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong today. I have been developing react app for a while. the old ...
npm create-react-app, your suggestion of npm init react-app . or, npm init react-app my-app. No matter what I try, I am getting the error mentioned above. My npm is 6.7.0 and node is 8.11.1.

I am not sure but something it not right.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did (hack) to make it work but, I highly recommend, whoever is responsible for this library fix this.

In the node-modules (generated via any of create-react-app app-name, OR npm init react-app app-name, OR npx create-react-app app-name ... whatever) ... go to the directory
node=modules/avj/lib/keywords.js ... and go to line 65 that has this:

if (!validateDefinition(definition))
  throw new Error('custom keyword definition is invalid: '  + this.errorsText(validateDefinition.errors));

Comment this out as:

```
//  if (!validateDefinition(definition))
   //   throw new Error('custom keyword definition is invalid: '  + 
   // this.errorsText(validateDefinition.errors));
```

save ... and return to the directory and >> npm start

Note: This is a hack and I do not know what is the long term effect. Also, if you hack it, then ... if you try to deploy the app in a cloud (say Heroku) that would generate from the package.json file, it will recreate those line and the application will not start in the cloud. Hence, this is not recommended unless you are just trying to get past the stupid error.